# MYSQLでグルーピングして一覧表示したい

Tags: mysql, sql

MYSQLの初歩的な質問なのですが、以下のようなテーブルがあったときにtitleでグルーピングして日付の新しい順に一覧表示したいと思っています。
このときのSELECT文をおしえていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

＜元のテーブル＞

```
id  title  date
---------------------
1   AAAAA  2017/06/20
2   BBBBB  2017/06/19
3   AAAAA  2017/06/18
4   CCCCC  2017/06/17
5   BBBBB  2017/06/20
```

＜Select結果＞

```
id  title  date
---------------------
1   AAAAA  2017/06/20
3   AAAAA  2017/06/18
5   BBBBB  2017/06/20
2   BBBBB  2017/06/19
4   CCCCC  2017/06/17
```

Answer (score 1):

やりたいのは、「title が同じ行を隣同士にして、その中で日付の逆順に並べたい」ということでしょうか? 前者もソートで実現出来ますから、次のように `ORDER BY` を利用して複数条件でソートするとよいでしょう。(`ASC` は昇順、`DESC` は降順を表しますが、昇順の `ASC` は省略可能です。)

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
ORDER BY title ASC, date DESC;
```

(まずはSQLの入門書を一通り読むのが近道かと思います。)

Comment: ありがとうございます！少しだけかじっただけのSQLだったので改めて入門書を読んで見たいと思います。

Comment: すいません。書籍到着までの間に追加で質問させてください。

Comment: すいません。書籍到着までの間に追加で質問させてください。<br/> 
①「title が同じ行を隣同士にして、その中で日付の逆順に並べた」ものをさらに②「タイトルの日付の中で一番大きいものの日付を逆順」に表示するにはどのようにやればいいのでしょうか？  
・・・うまく説明できずに申し訳ありません。    

①の結果  
`id  title  date  
---------------------  
3  AAAAA  2017-01-25  
1  AAAAA  2017-01-02  
2  BBBBB  2017-01-01  
6  CCCCC  2017-01-20  
4  CCCCC  2017-01-08`  
  
  
②（やりたいこと）  
`  
id  title  date  
---------------------  
3  AAAAA  2017-01-25←ここの日付で並び替え  
1  AAAAA  2017-01-02  
6  CCCCC  2017-01-20←ここの日付で並び替え  
4  CCCCC  2017-01-08  
2  BBBBB  2017-01-01←ここの日付で並び替え`

Comment: @krk 新しい質問は新規で作成してください。(コメントだとややこしくなるので。)

Comment: ありがとうございます。承知致しました！